# Rails 3 nesting objects creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Would like some help with nesting association, i have a two deep level association, i can do single level nesting with no problems but having trouble with 2deep levels.

Routes.rb

```
 resources :releases do 
      resources :features
 end

 resources :features do 
      resources :issues
 end
```

View Create New Issue

```
<%= link_to "Create New Issue", new_feature_issue_path(@feature) %>
```

Controller.

```
def create
        @issue = @feature.issues.build(params[:issue])
        if @issue.save
            flash[:notice] = "Issue has been created."
            redirect_to [@feature, @issue]
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Issue has not been created."
            render :action => "new"
        end

    end
```

show view:

```
<div id='issue'>
    <h2><%= @issue.title %></h2>
    <%= simple_format(@issue.description) %>
</div>
```

Error msg:

```
undefined method `issues' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Can you show the code of show action..

Comment: The show method is blank, is the problem that the feature object is a child of 'releases' which has not been added to the redirect url?

Comment: What do the models for Releases, Features, and Issues look like? What does the new action in the FeatureController contain? Try building the associations you need in the console first to check that the models are set up right?

Comment: @feature = release.features.build

Comment: dont know what i'm doing wrong, its not receiving the issues model for some reason. am i right to do it this way? i didn't want to do /release/2/feature/3/issue/5 kind of route

Answer (score 0):

You first find feature and then you can view issues against it...

reading carefully from these links

http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

http://pandejo.blogspot.com/2009/03/rails-nested-resources-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

If your show action is nil, then you won't have the `@issue` variable set.  The redirect call in creates an entirely new request which won't have the `@issue` set.  You need to re-create your @issue assignment in the controller's show method.

Comment: how come i don't have anything in my features-controllers show action?

Comment: ok got the show working thanks to your help, but create is stopping at the create line

Comment: You'll need to share more code in the original question.  Show the code you're using to generate the form and the parts of the models showing the has_many & belongs_to relationships.